# Meteor js publish and subscribe is very slow to react

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, d3.js

I have used meteor publish and subscribe method to interact with client and server. Now according to my scenario I am using D3 js to generate a bar chart and as soon as the data is entered in mongo db collection I am using a client side function to generate a bar chart. My issue is that publish and subscribe is too slow to react. And even if I limit the number of documents returned by mongodb, the issue still persists. It is also inconsistent i.e. it will react under 1 second sometimes and other times it will take 4-5 second. Please guide me on what to do and what is wrong with my implementation.

Here is the server side code,

```
Test = new Mongo.Collection("test")

Meteor.publish('allowedData', function() {
    return Test.find({});
})
```

and here is the client side code,

```
Test = new Mongo.Collection("test")
 Meteor.subscribe('allowedData');
 Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    Test.find().observe({
    added: function(document){
        //something
    },
    changed:function(){
        //something
    },
    removed:function(){
        //something
    },
    })
```

Comment: I think it is more elegant to import `Test` from a general file

Comment: Did you check TimeLine (in Chrome browser) to see loading times per operation?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No. I didn't check the TimeLine. And I am not getting what you mean by this, "I think it is more elegant to import Test from a general file "

Comment: You publish all `Test` documents to client, so there is no doubt that it will be slow. You should consider using method to generate data for the chart instead

Comment: Use Meteor methods to get only the information you need. Remove the `Test.find().observe()` from the client completely.

Comment: Actually what I need to accomplish is that, whenever a document is added in the mongoDB then I need to display that in the bar chart. So i need it to be reactive and hence I have used observe().

Answer (score 2):

From your comments I see that you need a report chart which is reactive. Even though it is your requirement, it is too expensive to have a chart like this. In fact when you system grows bigger, say you have around 10000 documents for one single chart, this kind of chart will crash your server frequently.

To work around this problem, I have two suggestions:

- Define a method that returns data for the chart. Set up a job/interval timer in client to call that method periodically. The interval value depends on your need, 10 seconds should be fine for charts. It is not completely reactive this way, you only get the newest data after an interval but it is still better than a slow and crash-frequent system. You could find good modules to manage job/timer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=schedule&page=1&ranking=optimal).
- Use this Meteor package [meteor-publish-join](https://github.com/nlhuykhang/meteor-publish-join) (disclaimer: I am the author), it is made to solve the kind of problem you have: the need to do reactive aggregations/joins on a big data set and still have a good overall performance

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. As far as your first option goes, I thought the same but I am not allowed to do so. But I will definitely look at your second option.